# How to do a workaround in css that removes spacing in footer of navigator7 vaadin addon

Tags: css, vaadin

I am using vaadin in combination with navigator7 addon. In header and footer there are spacings between conponents That i would not have. I tried to remove the spacings using setSpacing(false) for header and footer component but it is not working probably becouse of the addon.
So i tried to solve this using css. The sample below i a test output html that vaadin generates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div div .footer-label, .footer-label{
color: green;
width: 100px !important;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="my-footer">
<div>
<div style="color: red; height: 20px; width: 482px; overflow: hidden; float: left;    padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; background-color:yellow;">
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 0px;">
<button class="footer-label" style="width: 400px;">Text</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

There is a button inside div div. I would like to make the width of root div to have exact same width as the button.

I ended with this css code but it does not work. The root div stays in its 482 pixels width.

```
div div .footer-label, .footer-label{
color: green;
width: 100px !important;
}
```

**Vaadin Code**

```
 public class MyAppLevelWindow extends HeaderFooterFixedAppLevelWindow {    

    @Override
    protected Component createHeader() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected Component createFooter() {
        HorizontalLayout myFooter = new HorizontalLayout();
        akmedFooter.setSpacing(false);
        akmedFooter.setStyleName("my-footer");

        NativeButton sendProblemButton = new NativeButton("Button");
        sendProblemButton.setStyleName("footer-label");
        myFooter.addComponent(sendProblemButton);
        .....

        return myFooter;
    }

    .............
    }
```

Please help me make a workaround using css to solve this problem.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i would like to resize multiple objects like that, not only one.

Comment: Answers here suggesting to use a CSS style with !important to size a element take a wrong approach. Normally you should not try to set sizes for Components with CSS in Vaadin. You should provide some Vaadin code to see how to solve the problem.

Comment: @HenriKerola I have no idea of whether you are correct about setting sizes for componenents in Vaadin as it is not something that I have used. To me (and presumably the other people who answered), the question was pretty much "how do I do this using CSS". Feel free to edit the question and the title to reflect what you bleieve the question should be and we can answer that one instead.

Comment: @MarcinWiankowski if what Henri Kerola says is correct then I think you should add your Vaadin code so we can see why you are getting inline styles (by the sounds of things this is not a normal scenario) and suggest a more robust answer. You should be able to unaccept my answer.

Comment: @MarcinWiankowski please provide a simplified Vaadin code, that shows the problem.

Comment: I added Vaadin Code. But i think the answer i posted is good becouse the unwanted spacing is caused by navigator7 addon. And after removing spacing i can still use java code to resize components in footer.

Comment: Navigator7 adds div with width:482px;

Comment: @MarcinWiankowski thanks for the code, I added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is that FixedApplLevelWindow sets a fixed width for header and footer returned from the createHeader() and createFooter() methods. See pageWidth in FixedApplLevelWindow. This means that the HorizontalLayout returned from your createFooter() method gets this width, and HorizontalLayout works in this case so that it divides the width for the child components of the layout so that every component gets the same size. So there is not actually spacing between the components inside the footer, the slot of a component is just larger than component's width. Try to say setWidth("100%") for the component inside your footer layout and the "spacing" is gone. Now components use all the space available in slots.

One way to fix this problem is that you wrap your component inside another HorizontalLayout. The width of a HorizontalLayout is undefined (setWidth(null)) by default which means the layout calculates its width from its children.

```
protected Component createFooter() {
    HorizontalLayout myFooter = new HorizontalLayout();
    myFooter.setStyleName("my-footer");

    HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();

    NativeButton sendProblemButton = new NativeButton("Button 1");
    sendProblemButton.setStyleName("footer-label");
    layout.addComponent(sendProblemButton);

    NativeButton sendProblemButton2 = new NativeButton("Button 2");
    sendProblemButton2.setStyleName("footer-label");
    layout.addComponent(sendProblemButton2);

    myFooter.addComponent(layout);

    return myFooter;
}
```

See [6.12 Layout Formatting](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.settings.html) from Book of Vaadin for more information.

Comment: Ahh I added my components in footer do new HorizontalLayout which is added to myFooter ant it works. It was so easy :/ Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
div div .footer-label{
color: green;
width: 100px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The width seems to be set via javascript or directly inline, server-side. You should first prevent this behaviour, for example by calling some jQuery javascript:

```
$('body > div').css({width: ""});
```

Then, this css should work

```
body > div{
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

Comment: But in the code i posted it is not changed by javascript or on the server side. So if you could change it here it could probably work on the webapp.